# Request to migrate a question

Tags: support

About 4 years ago, I asked [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/120959/what-is-a-good-nimh-charger), which was closed as off-topic, but is now on topic in [a recently created SE site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  Can someone migrate this question?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't migrate old questions, unfortunately.  The SE system doesn't allow to migrate questions older than 90 days.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Especially when the site in question is new, and can use quality questions from another site.  I guess I'll just re-post it then.

Comment: You should still be able to edit the old question, and copy-paste the entire thing verbatim (including Markdown, etc.) to the new site.

Comment: This probably wouldn't be on topic on hardware recs - its still "computer" focused as opposed to general hardware recs like this